# Neural Network train and val accuracy score is 0.00000

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Developing a neural network for the Spaceship Titanic comp binary classification problem.  However, I keep getting a score of 0.0000 for train and val data, and can't figure out why.  Models have worked for knn, lightxgb and random forest, so I don't think it's a data issue.

Code as below

```
print(X_train_scaled.shape)
print(y_train2.shape)

(6085, 23)
(6085, 1)

# Create model
model1 = Sequential()

model1.add(Dense(18, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_dim = X_train_scaled.shape[1]))
model1.add(Dense(9, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model1.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

history = model1.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train2, batch_size=100, epochs=30, validation_split = 0.3)

Epoch 1/30
43/43 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7348 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.6989 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/30
43/43 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6603 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.6324 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/30
43/43 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5994 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.5784 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/30
43/43 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5539 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.5401 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in place of:

```
metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
```

try:

```
metrics=['accuracy']
```

Comment: Oh my ... you're an absolute star... how easy is that answer... I've been working on this for a day and it was killing me!!  Thank you!!!